# Is it possible to specify OAuth callback URL for Custom Integrations in Autodesk BIM360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

For existing applications in BIM360 there is the option to specify OAuth callback URL.
But for Custom Integrations Apps there is no such option.
Is it possible to specify OAuth callback URL for Custom Integrations in Autodesk BIM360?

Comment: I may miss something, could you elaborate the scenario of  [For existing applications in BIM360 there is the option to specify OAuth callback URL] ? With my knowledge, oAuth callback url is specified when you created Forge app (which also generates client id and secret). I do not seem to see anywhere in BIM360 that asks for callback URL

Comment: Yes, you are right. Problem was that for BIM 360 custom integration I used client_id and client_secret from app that already has been created, I didn't know that callback url is specified when you create app in Forge, I though it is specified when you add custom integration to the account.

Comment: yes, callback url is specified when creating Forge app, but callback is defined by the developer who produced the web app. It is for  getting oauth code when the web app user (also the BIM360 users) wants to authorize the web app to access the his/her data in BIM360. but  Integration does not need to know the callback url.

Comment: do you have any special context you must know the callback url?  as said above, it is for web app, instead of the user or BIM360 admin. The admin only need to aprove the integration (add client id to the BIM360 account with Admin/Docs permission)

Comment: @XiaodongLiang, Thank you for the help. I know how to use callback URL, everything works fine, just couldn't find place where it is specified in Autodesk world. Thanks!